# Parse key/value pairs from MSBuild property

Tags: msbuild

Say I have a property like:

```
<MyProp>Foo=Bar;Hello=World</MyProp>
```

This seems like a reasonably common property pattern in MSBuild. How would I go about fetching the value "World"? In an ideal world this might look something like:

```
$(MyProp).(Hello)
```

Edit: To be clear, the property is *not* of my own creation, it is the output from another target that is out of my control, so I cannot change the way the property is declared.

Comment: See my edited response.You can take the third approach if no concrete solution was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyProp>Foo=Bar;Hello=World</MyProp>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Foo">
        <CreateItem Include="MyProp" AdditionalMetadata="$(MyProp)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="MyProp" />
        </CreateItem>
        <Message Text="Foo %(MyProp.Foo)" />
        <Message Text="Hello %(MyProp.Hello)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: 100% effective, and quite elegant given the constraints of MSBuild. Thanks.

Comment: Minor correction: the AdditionalMetadata attribute receives an array of string, so the way it works for me is with:  AdditionalMetadata="$(MyProp.Split(';'))"

Answer (score 1):

You have two routes to follow as far as I am concerned

1. Declare a [Property Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4w159bs.aspx) just like the following:

> ```
>  <PropertyGroup>
>      <Foo>Bar</Foo>
>      <Hello>World</Hello>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```

and then use the following method to access your properties

> ```
> <Target Name="DoSomething">
> <Message Text="Print this : $(Foo)" />
> </Target>
> ```

or you  might want to take [ItemGroup Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx) approach like the following

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MySolutionFiles Include="..\mySolution.sln" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="PrintItems">
     <Message Text="My Files: @(MySolutionFiles)" />
</Target>
```

You can have the following as well

> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>     <MyProp
>     Include="Foo;Hello" />
> </ItemGroup>
> <Target Name="PrintMyItems">
>      <Message Text="MyProp: @(MyProp)" />
> </Target>
> ```

If there is no choice over the input then one possible solution is parsing the input into an array and then taking it from there like the following:

> ```
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     <MyProp>Foo=Bar;Hello=World</MyProp>
>     <Split>$(MyProp.Split(';'))</Split>
>   </PropertyGroup>
> ```

and then play with the array items like the following:

> ```
>   <Target Name="DoPrint">
>     <Message text="$(Split[0])" />
>   </Target>
> ```

Split[0] item contains your Foo=Bar which can be split into two more strings just like above. This should keep you going for now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a property group, it's just nice to have default values in case the user doesn't pass them.

For each property you pass, the syntax to access that property is $(PropertyName).

So if you pass:

msbuild.exe /p:P1=V1 /p:P2=V2;P3=V3

You would use the property name $(P1), $(P2), $(P3).

More on MsBuild properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx).

Comment: See my edit, I don't have the choice of changing how the property is declared.